# iOS XCode6 backward compatibility issue

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have a project that was started with XCode5. After iPhone 6 and 6 plus was released, I switched to XCode6.

At the beginning, my app worked well on the lager screen of iPhone 6 and 6 plus (simulator) - they just got stretched, and that is the behavior I want. However, all of a sudden, I don't even know why, my app doesn't get stretched on the larger screen of iPhone 6 and 6 plus anymore, it is now using the exact constraint, and the size that I set for any of my views on screen. So for example I have many widths set to be "320", now all of them are exact 320 points wide on screen, making the screen a mess.

My question is that is there a way to tell XCode6 that I would like it to continue doing that "stretch" for my project?

Comment: You should never assume that screens have a specific height or width. The goal of Auto Layout is to support dynamic widths and heights and setting a fixed width of 320 works against that. You'll have to update your app's design.

Comment: @fluidsonic That is the long term goal, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it happened.

I added a launch screen xib file and set the `Launch screen interface file base name` property in the info.plist, that makes XCode6 think that I am ready to handle the layout on larger screens myself.

After deleting the launch screen xib file, deleting that `Launch screen interface file base name` property in the info.plist and using a static image as the launch screen, XCode6 is now stretching my app again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. First go to your story board; then select the UI object which you have added to your view controller; at the right in the bottom of the standard editor there are four little items which one of them is a triangle between two vertical lines. click on it, there are many options, you have to choose "Add missing constraints". Finally run your app, it may work fine.